# Is it Possible to Tell if the Project Application is Project Professional/Standard via Code?

Tags: ms-project

I want to be able to check if the [application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application) is Project Professional via code. I don't see anything obvious in the API that would do this. Is it possible?

I tried looking at the [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.version) property, but that only returns the version number. Same thing with the [Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.build) property.

Comment: The GUIDs will be different between Standard and Professional. This might point you in the right direction: [Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in Office 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/numbering-scheme-for-product-guid).